# Quartz or java timer service for database polling

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, scheduling

I need some assistance on whether I should be using Quartz or simply use the Java timer service.

I am building an application which will poll the database every second for a status change. When there is a "successful" status I will get that entry from the table and do some processing before sending it off to another server.

The database table would likely have a lot of entries. Expecting there to be 1000s. Maybe 10,000s

This of course needs to be multithreaded.
1 thread to do the polling
Perhaps a thread pool to manage the processing and sending a request to another server efficiently

I had looked at Quartz and the java Timer. Quartz seems a but overboard for what I need to do since I'll only need one timer.

So my questions are:
With my requirements is Quartz suitable?
I'll need to poll every second or half a second on possibly 10,000s DB table entries does Quartz handle this ok?

Comment: @DecrypterDo you solve your issue?